# How do I reference $this inside of a class { function { function }}?

Tags: php, function, scope

I have a php class `Assets`.  Within `Assets` there are a variety of public functions which handle assets (caching, minifying, combining...).  One of the public functions contains a secondary function which is required to perform a `preg_replace_callback()`.  This inner function needs to access one of the other public functions but I am having trouble calling the other functions.

**Here is the setup:**

```
class Assets
{

    public function img($file)
    {

        $image['location'] = $this->image_dir.$file;
        $image['content'] = file_get_contents($image['location']);
        $image['hash'] = md5($image['content']);
        $image['fileInfo'] = pathinfo($image['location']);

        return $this->cache('img',$image);

    }

    public function css($content)
    {

        . . .

        function parseCSS($matched){

            return $this->img($matched); // THIS LINE NEEDS TO REFERENCE function img()

        }

        $mend = preg_replace_callback(
            '#\<parse\>(.+?)\<\/parse\>#i',
            'parseCSS',
            $this->combined_css
        );

        . . .

    }

}
```

**Here's what I have tried:**

> `$this->img($matched)`
>
> *Error: Using $this when not in object context - Refers to `$this->`
>   inside of `parseCSS()`*
>
> `Assets::img($matched)`
>
> *Error: Using $this when not in object context - Refers to `$this->`
>   inside of `img()`*

So, **how can I access a public function with `$this` from within an inner function?**

Comment: Why are you wrapping functions in methods? That doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: ^ It's also bad practice.  Maintainability goes out the window..

Comment: Bro, don't declare a function within a function.

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like functions... :)

Comment: Is there any sort of logical reason you're doing this?

Comment: functions within functions can be useful in javascript but php? not so much.

Comment: I need to call a function with `preg_replace_callback`, that is the only reason that I would have a function within a function.  Do you have an alternate method to use `preg_replace_callback`?  Even using `create_function` within `preg_replace_callback` does not work.

Comment: How is this "not a real question?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This would be more appropriate:

```
public function css($content)
{
    //. . .
    $mend = preg_replace_callback(
        '#\<parse\>(.+?)\<\/parse\>#i',
        array($this, 'parseCSS'),
        $this->combined_css
    );
    //. . .
}

public function parseCSS($matched){
    return $this->img($matched); // THIS LINE NEEDS TO REFERENCE function img()
}
```

Your original approach causes `parseCSS` to be defined every time `css` is called -- which will probably result in a fatal error were you to ever call `css` twice.  All questions of scope are also much more straightforward in my revised example.  In your original example, `parseCSS` is a function in the global scope, and not associated with your class.

Edit: Valid callback formulations are documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

```
// Type 1: Simple callback
call_user_func('my_callback_function'); 

// Type 2: Static class method call
call_user_func(array('MyClass', 'myCallbackMethod')); 

// Type 3: Object method call
call_user_func(array($obj, 'myCallbackMethod'));

// Type 4: Static class method call (As of PHP 5.2.3)
call_user_func('MyClass::myCallbackMethod');

// Type 5: Relative static class method call (As of PHP 5.3.0)
call_user_func(array('B', 'parent::who')); // A

//Type 6: Closure
$double = function($a) {
    return $a * 2;
};

$new_numbers = array_map($double, $numbers);
```

A [closure](http://php.net/closure)-based solution is also possible as of PHP 5.4 -- this would actually be similar to what you originally intended.

Comment: I was not aware that I could include scope within that second parameter.  I had tried to remove `parseCSS` into a private function, but passing `'$this->parseCSS'` as the second parameter in `preg_replace_callback` did not work.  The code you provided works wonderfully.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

That doesn't do what you think it does. That "inner" function is just another function in the **global** scope:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        echo 'in bar';

        function baz() {
            echo 'in baz';
        }
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar();
baz();
```

Also note that it will result in a *fatal error* when calling the `bar` method more than once:

```
<?php
class Foo
{
    public function bar()
    {
        echo 'in bar';

        function baz() {
            echo 'in baz';
        }
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
$foo->bar();
$foo->bar();
baz();
```

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare baz() (previously declared in /code/8k1

You should go the way as [Frank Farmer answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13055231/508666) although I would not make that method `public`.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was clearly mixing up some of my javascript and php knowledge... or lack there of.